# Query does not use index when used as a view

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle11g

I wrote a query that when executed on several values - uses the table's index and returns results quickly.

When I created a view using the very same syntax, the index sometimes remain unused.

For example: when querying the following query, the index DEP_IDX is used, and the query takes a few seconds to return results:

```
Select /*+INDEX (s DEP_IDX) */ department, avg(salary) as dep_avg
From salaries s
Where department in (1,4,7,8)
Group by department
```

When I create a view using the same syntax, like this:

```
Create or replace view Departments_Avg_Salary as
  Select /*+INDEX (s DEP_IDX)*/ department, avg(salary) as dep_avg
  From salaries s
  Group by department
```

And then use the view in a query:

```
Select e.Employee_Name, e.Employee_Salary, d.dep_avg
From Employees​ e Left join
     Departments_Avg_Salary d
     On d.department = e.Employees_Department
Where e.Employee_Name in ('Michael', 'Nittai', 'Jack')
```

The Index is not used and the query takes a lifetime to return!

As you can see, using the INDEX hint made no difference...

As it turns out, given the table's​ huge size, there will be no scenario in which using table access storage full will be the efficient way, so I am really looking for a solution that will force the DB to use the index.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not the same queries.  Run an explain plan and post the results.

Comment: Do you really need to outer join to your view? (i.e. are there any employees that do not have a department associated with them?) If not, then check whether the query with inner join performs better...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off writing the query like this:

```
Select e.Employee_Name, e.Employee_Salary,
       (select avg(s.salary)
        from salaries s
        where s.department = e.Employees_Department
       ) avg_salary
From Employees​ e 
Where e.Employee_Name in ('Michael', 'Nittai', 'Jack');
```

And then having indexes on `employees(Employee_name)` and `salaries(department, salary)`.

The index in your original query is probably being used for the `WHERE` clause, not the `GROUP BY`.  As for hints in views, I would start with the warning in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i22087):

> Oracle does not encourage the use of hints inside or on views (or
>   subqueries). This is because you can define views in one context and
>   use them in another. Also, such hints can result in unexpected
>   execution plans. In particular, hints inside views or on views are
>   handled differently, depending on whether the view is mergeable into
>   the top-level query.

Answer (score 0):

Your standalone query includes this WHERE clause:

```
Where department in (1,4,7,8)
```

So it would be efficient to use an index to retrieve records for a few departments.

Your view does not filter on by department so it's going to execute a Full Table Scan. What you're hoping is that the query using the view is going to push the `department` predicate into the view's query ...

```
From Employees​ e Left join
     Departments_Avg_Salary d
     On d.department = e.Employees_Department
```

... but alas the optimizer doesn't work like that